# is it normal disabling testing device in app account doesn't stop ad hoc app

Tags: ios, sign

After disabling a device from the provisioning profile for ad hoc distribution, a new mobileprovision was generated and it was used to re-bundle a new ipa. The testing device whose udid was disabled in the apple account, was used to download the same app that the device was disable from. After a short wait, app was successfully downloaded and it was working.

This is strange, I have an impression that it would prevent anyone who doesn't have the right permission to download. Was there a step missing from here?

**Addition**

The app can be download over the air, but it can't be install by sideload if the device is disabled in the .mobileproven. Both use the same provision.